# "Use X for" vs. "Use X with"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

> Do not use any indentation styles other than K&R, Allman, and their mix, which uses K&R [**for**|**with**] control flow statements and Allman [**for**|**with**] function definitions.
>
> ```
> // K&R         // Allman     // A mix of K&R and Allman
> if (...) {     if (...)      function()
>     ...        {             {
> } else {           ...           if (...) {
>     ...        }                     ...
> }              else              } else {
>                {                     ...
>                    ...           }
>                }             }
> ```

I don't understand whether I should use **for** or **with** in sentences like the one above.

(Surprisingly, there are no related articles or forum threads on the Internet.) Could you explain it to me?

Comment: Both prepositions ***for, with*** are fine, as also would be ***in***, and possibly others. There's no real need for online forums to spend a lot of time discussing such things, because the meaning is obvious regardless, and the primary purpose of such technical documentation is to *communicate*, not to showcase writing skills.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Do you have any personal preference?

Comment: To be honest, I'd probably mostly tend to use ***in*** myself anyway. But (outside the context of answering your question here) I wouldn't give it much thought. And if I had to write the same thing several times over, sufficiently far apart that I didn't remember which preposition I'd used *last* time, I'm sure that I'd use at least all those three (and perhaps others) from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat a matter of opinion and style. Prepositions can often be used interchangeably  in English.

"For" is a more direct and unambiguous preposition to use in the example. You use a tool (or a type of indent formatting) *for* something -- for this type of code *to be formatted correctly*.

You may also use a tool "with" something, but that shifts the meaning somewhat from a description of purpose to a description of connection.

To summarize the question shows that "for" and "with" are both understandable:

*Which indent should be used for different types of code statements?*

*Which indent should be used with different types of code statements?*

You can think of "for" and "with" actually standing for these longer phrases:

For -- "for the purpose of" formatting this code correctly.

With -- "in connection with" this code's correct formatting.